# How to fix Google play console terminated accounts?

Tags: google-play-console

What is the solution after console account termination?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHkVD.png)

I need the solution to fix the issues.

Comment: There is nothing you can do, there is no appeal. Google has decided you cannot have a developer account. Also, your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: have you solved your case @October?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do anything other than contacting the *policy support team*. Any other solution will be considered as a violation.